# Как задать в GridLayout (под Android) максимальную ширину столбца?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-layout

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь разобраться с GridLayout. Вроде удобная штука, но...
Стоит простая задача на экран вывести 2 ImageButton, но так чтобы их размеры растягивались самостоятельно на экране. 
По логике с этим должен справляться GridLayout. Не могу понять какое свойство настраивать...
Пока съезжают картинки, так как левая больше и сама она не уменьшается.

P.s. размеры картинок не меняю, так как на разных устройствах размер разный, стало быть как-то это свойствами можно сделать. Только не знаю как...[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="3"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonCow"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/cow"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonPig"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/pig"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: XML с GridView покажи

Comment: Добавила в описание вопроса. В коммент не влазит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тут все несколько нетривиально, хотя ничего военного. Проблема в том что GridLayout научился разбивать пропорционально (использовать вес) только с версии Android v21. К счастью GridLayout есть в support library, его только нужно подключить: 
для этого нужно подключить сам модуль `gridlayout` из каталога `androidSdk/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout`, `android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar` который лежит в папке `libs` у этого модуля, и `android-support-v4.jar`.

**UPD:** 
Если использовать Android Studio то подключить их совсем просто, в файле `build.gradle` у модуля `app`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

**UPD2:**
Также предварительно нужно в SDK Manager выкачать последние Tools (Tools, Platform-tools, Build-tools), Android SDK и Android Support Repository (в низу списка).

Сам xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        app:columnCount="2"
        >

    <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/asdf"/>

    <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/asdf"/>

    <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/asdf"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

[image: Пример GridLayout с весом]